# Why is StringValues used for Request.Query values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Let's say I have some url that looks like this: www.myhost.com/mypage?color=blue

In Asp.Net Core, I'd expect to get the color query parameter value by doing the following:

`string color = Request.Query["color"];`

But it turns out that the `Request.Query["color"]` returns a value of type `StringValues` rather than `string`.  Why is that?

Apparently the `StringValues` type can hold an array of strings and includes support for implicit conversion to `string[]` which is cool but why is that needed for a query param value?

Having to get the value like this seems odd:

`string color = Request.Query["color"].ToString();`

And worse, checking for a value to see if a query param is specified can no longer be done like so

```
  if(Request.Query["color"] == null) { 
      //param was not specified
  }
```

but instead must be checked like so

```
 if(Request.Query["color"].Count == 0) { 
      //param was not specified
 }
```

Since a single query parameter can't have multiple values (as far as I know) why does `Request.Query["color"]` return a `StringValues` object rather than a string?

Comment: What would you expect the value to be for www.myhost.com/mypage?color=blue&color=red&color=green

Comment: @podiluska I didn't know it was valid to specify a parameter multiple times.  If I had done so I'd have expected to just receive the last one i.e. green in your example.

Comment: Don’t use `Request.Query`, use [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) instead.

Comment: @RonC Im pretty sure thats the way querystrings *used* to work. But the current "wisdom" in providing collections on the querystring is to repeat the key. Whether you and I agree with that is pretty irrelevant :)

Comment: @Jamiec  Gotcha.  :-)

Comment: you can use 
`var color = Request.Query["color"];

    if (StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(color)) 
         {
            // do something 
        };`

Answer (score 91, accepted):

As already mentioned by others, the type is a `StringValues` object because technically, multiple values are allowed. While the common practice is to just set a single value, the URI specification does not disallow setting values multiple times. And it’s up to the application to decide how to handle that.

That being said, `StringValues` has an implicit conversion to `string`, so you don’t actually need to call `ToString()` on it, you can just use it as if it was a string. So doing things like `Request.Query["color"] == "red"`, or passing it to a method that expects a string will just work.

> And worse, checking for a value to see if a query param is specified can no longer be done like so `Request.Query["color"] == null` but instead must be checked like so `Request.Query["color"].Count == 0`

That’s only half true. Yes, in order to check whether a `StringValues` object is empty, you can check its `Count` property. You can also check against `StringValues.Empty`:

```
Request.Query["color"] == StringValues.Empty
```

However, the initial “issue” is that `Request.Query[x]` will **always** return a non-null `StringValues` object (so it’s safe to check for any value). If you want to check whether a key exists in the query arguments, you should use `ContainsKey`:

```
if (Request.Query.ContainsKey("color"))
{
    // only now actually retrieve the value
    string colorValue = Request.Query["color"];
}
```

Or alternatively, use `TryGetValue`:

```
if (Request.Query.TryGetValue("color", out var colorValue))
{
    DoSomething(colorValue);
}
```

---

That all being said, accessing `Request.Query` is not really necessary most of the times. You should just use make use of [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) instead which will automatically give you the query arguments you need by just having them in the action’s signature:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string color)
{
    DoSomething(color);
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out that `StringValues` does support implicit conversion to `string` so that `String color= Request.Query["color"];` does in fact work.  I thought I had seen otherwise, my bad.

Comment: This is one of those times I wish I could transfer the OP's accepted mark to a different answer. While mine technically "answers" the question this should have received the recognition of being the right answer. Especially the last bit about not calling `Query` directly, but using model binding.

Comment: I would recommend using `StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty()` instead of `Count == 0`. You'll need to add a `using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives`

Comment: @Steve In my answer, I am actually arguing *against* checking the _value_ but checking whether the key exists instead. That being said, `StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty` does have slightly different semantics compared to a check against Empty or checking the count.

Comment: @Jamiec  Sorry it took me so long to notice your comment about changing the accepted mark.  I agree and have changed it.  I didn't initially because your answer was the first one that helped me understand the situation but I agree with you that this answer is the more robust one.

Comment: From what I have seen, model binding works great if the values being passed are required and not dynamic. If the values being passed are dynamic and/or not always required, query string is best. Currently I have a set of reports where I use both model binding and query string together. I use model binding to pass the Id of the report (always required), but the data parameters are different and varying in number every time (dynamic), so I use a query string to pass the report data parameters. Breaking it up this way makes the parsing a little easier for me and the code easier to read.

Answer (score 68):

Because your query can look like this:

> www.myhost.com/mypage?color=blue&color=red&color=yellow

And you get all those `color` values from the one `Request.Query["color"]` parameter

Comment: thanks, I was unaware that it was valid to specify the same query parameter multiple times in a query string.  Given how often it's used on the web (Never seen it before and been doing web development since 1995) I wish it wasn't allowed given that it makes the code less elegant for a seldom used edge case.  But now I understand why 'StringValues' was introduced.  Interestingly the concept of `StringValues` wasn't introduced until Asp.Net Core, prior versions of Asp.Net returned string.

Comment: I wonder why the QueryHelpers.AddQueryString in .NET Core is: QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(string uri, IDictionary<string, string> queryString)

Answer (score 12):

Just posting for curious souls and probably little do with question. Just cautionary note.

I found myself in similar issue. There are couple other issues with this type.

1. If you have query parameter with no value. For example: `/products?pageNo=1&pageSize=`

   You will find yourself getting an exception thrown for `pageSize` parameter as `Count`
   property on `StringValues` will give you value 1, but underlying `_value` is `""` (empty
   string) and `_values` is `null`. Note - Exception happens you are trying to convert or
   access values from IQueryCollection)
2. Using `TryGetValue` will get you value safely out of `StringValues` but if it is null
   (like in case of `pageSize` parameter above), You will have hard time figuring out why
   can't you convert `StringValues` to simple `String` or why can not compare with `null` to
   do further operations on it like validations etc.
3. To do any checking on `StringValues` type, use methods provided by the type.

To check for null or empty use - `StringValues.IsNullOrEmpty(StringValues value)`

Comment: Your response is very much related to the question.  It's interesting that `StringValue.IsNullOrEmpty(StringValue value)` works.  As I mentioned, I ended up checking for null by using `Request.Query["color"].Count == 0` but your approach reads better I think.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the first string and are not expecting multiple values just do:

```cs
Request.Query["color"][0]
```

Answer (score -3):

`Request.Query["color"]` returns `StringValues` because collection of `string` values can be passed. So, I would suggest you to handle this as action parameter, model binding.

```
public ActionResult SaveColor([FromUri] string[] color);
```

Comment: What would this code return if the url were `www.myhost.com/mypage?color=blue&color=red&color=yellow` as @Jamiec and @podiluska mentioned might be the case.

Comment: If you want to expect list of strings change the parameter as "string[]".