# Replace Page.Request in ASP.NET Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am migrating project from Net 4.6.2 into Net Core 2.
What is the replacement for Request in MVC Net Core 2? How do I replace this line below? 
`string rawId = Request["ProductID"];`

In Net Core 2, I am receiving

**Error:**

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'HttpRequest'    HPE.Kruta.Web.Core
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest?view=netframework-4.7.2

**Code Example:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    string rawId = Request["ProductID"];  
    int productId;  
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rawId) && int.TryParse(rawId, out productId))  
    {  
        using (ShoppingCartActions usersShoppingCart = new ShoppingCar
```

Comment: Have you tried with 'string page = HttpContext.Request.Query["page"]'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET WebForms is not directly convertable to ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core because the "web form" paradigm does not translate well to the controller+action+model+binding system used in ASP.NET MVC. I recommend you read these other QAs first:

- [How to read values from the querystring with ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577376/how-to-read-values-from-the-querystring-with-asp-net-core)
- [Why is StringValues used for Request.Query values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188934/why-is-stringvalues-used-for-request-query-values)

The old `HttpRequest` object combined both `QueryString` and `Form` values together, but that's a bad design and now you need to explictly check one or the other (or both) so you know exactly where the value is coming from.

However, if you have a querystring value, you should make that a controller action parameter instead of using the `Request` object. You can use strongly-typed values (like `Int32` instead of `String` so you don't need to perform validation and conversion yourself. Like so:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetShoppingCart( [FromQuery] Int32 productId )
{
    ShoppingCart cart = await this.db.GetShoppingCartAsync( productId );

    ShoppingCartViewModel vm = new ShoppingCartViewModel()
    {
        Cart = cart
    };

    return this.View( model: vm );
}
```

However, if you would still prefer to access raw querystring or posted form values as their original string values, then do it like so.

Note that `Form` and `Query` are no-longer `NameValueCollection` objects but more strongly-typed classes that correctly expose "single key, multiple values" data more correctly. So do this to get the `"ProductId"` value like before:

```
String rawId = this.Request.Form["ProductId"].FirstOrDefault() ?? this.Request.Query["ProductId"].FirstOrDefault();
```

Because each `Form` entry is `StringValues` instead of `String` you need to always use `FirstOrDefault()` to get a single string value (don't use `SingleOrDefault()` because it will throw an exception if 2 or more values are present for the same key). Secondarily, the `??` operator will make the program check the querystring if the named value is not present in the posted `Form` values first.

The `Form` and `Query` collections return `StringValues.Empty` instead of `null` if the specified key is not found in either collection so you won't risk a `NullReferenceException` by using the `FirstOrDefault()` extension method if the key isn't present in the dictionary.